# Azure IoT Edge Offline Capabilities

Tags: gateway, azure-iot-edge, offline-mode

I had been trying to set up Azure IoT Edge in an environment which would have no internet connection after initialization.

In the documentation of IoT Edge, it's mentioned that inter-module communications can be achieved via routing, this I have tried and it worked.
However, I have a few leaf/child devices that I want them to be able to communicate with each other within the network. I was hoping to rely on IoT Edge and not install my own MQTT broker.

Problem:

- Seems like I can only invoke Direct Methods of other devices and not send messages to them. Devices seem to be only accepting C2D messages which won't be possible in the offline environment.
- Device Twin seems to be an IoT Hub only service as well. There is no local counterpart that lives on IoT Edge like AWS's local shadow service on Greengrass.

Had anyone done an end-to-end solution with Edge specifically with an internal network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Devices seem to be only accepting C2D messages" - what do you mean with this? you devices cannot react to direct methods (no matter if online or not)?

Comment: I mean I cannot route other messages to the devices via an Edge gateway. Or update the device twins on it from a module.

Comment: I think everything needs to go through edge device.So if you need to do device to device communication you need to do it through some broker.

Comment: Thanks @iAviator, have you implemented that yourself in a local/closed network with an external broker yourself? Did you use a docket container that is attached to Edge?

Comment: For C2d messages the device identity should be there in hub that is use either the transparent gateway design or the identity gateway design provided by Azure. So, it's seems you can't achieve through broker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @iAviator. I guess my problem started because I wanted to get rid of direct methods. And use a more MQTT native way of handling commands and status. So if we want to release code that would work on any provider it would be the same.
So I suppose what you are suggesting with Azure Edge. We either have to use hub with the cloud, having the solution online. Or we have to use direct methods in the Edge (no internet) situation?

Comment: Yes, and d2c message plus telemetry will also work in offline mode by edge.And regarding your custom solution I think you can achieve it throught MQTT which is just communication protocol anyone can use to write and read messages on a particular port.

Comment: @Derek You can also do d2d communication using http.The way I did was ran a module on edge which has node express server running and it exposed port 8080 to the host machine. Now my leaf device can call the http endpoint on host machine i.e the edge device.Above use case will work even if no internet is there just that the host and guest to be on same network. Similarly u can do communication between 2 non edge devices.

Comment: Thanks for the input @iAviator, that might work for me as well.